# Oracle virtual machine (Ubuntu) on windows 7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have windows 7 with Oracle Virtualbox 5.0.4 and Ubuntun image 15.10. I notice when I disable VirtualBox DHCP, and make network settings as Bridge, I could ping or ssh from host to guest. But at this time, I could not download package or sudo apt-get install xxx from internet.

when I still disable VirtualBox, I make network as NAT, then I could download package, but could not ping from host to guest.

How could I do both ping from host to guest and download from internet at guest(virtual box)?

Why I am doing that? We have project using kafka storm, solr as backend. (log management system). Client side could be Eclipse in windows, why I could put kakfa storm solr in virtualbox or vagrant, so that saving developer setting up development environment time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal bridge mode but this requires a external DHCP server. Normally in every office network is one. This server provides all needed networking/routing information. After you boot your VM you can test in a terminal if the VM is in the same network as your host.

Comment: Yes, I read several documents. There are a couple of ways. One way is above. The other just use NAT, with port forwarding. And shutdown firewall.